# Books on a shelf AN question

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

So I'm trying construct procedural node-graph in Animation Nodes to distribute books on a shelf (or any other surface). Getting them randomly from collection to certain location with random distance between them was not hard (the screenshot is attached). Where I encountered problems is when I wanted to have a random rotation, but to keep books from intersecting each other. I'm having hard time understanding which direction to go: 1. calculate certain rotation angle based on the distance between books or 2. calculate the distance based on the rotation of a book. Any way I go I cant construct a node graph that would accomplish this. I couldn't find anything on the web in this respect. Could anyone point me intro right direction in terms of tools to use and algorithm. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.
Cheers, David
[image]

Comment: Screenshot is missing

Comment: sorry. my mistake. added the screenshot.

Comment: This is not an answer but just an idea.
I'm a newbie in blender, but in cinema 4d i put a collider into the instanced object, so the instanced object it's pushed away from the object near it.